# Matlab: regexprep with variable

Tags: regex, matlab, regexp-replace

I have an array `a` : a list of identified words to be compared and replace by empty character in an array `b`. `newB` is the result.

The value of `a` might vary according to an input file.
I am trying to use `regexprep` but it is not working well.

e.g.:

```
a = {'apple';'banana';'orange'};     % a might be also ‘watermelon’, ‘papaya’ etc
b = {'1 apple = 2 kiwi';'1 fig = 1 banana';'1 orange = 3 strawberry'};
newB = {'  = 2 kiwi';'1 fig =  ';'  = 3 strawberry'};
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example it seems like you want to remove a special word and a number,  the appropriate regular expression for this is (for word = 'apple'): `'\d+ apple'`. Building the regular expression from all the words in `a`, using `sprintf`:

```
re = sprintf('\\d+ %s|',a{:}); %// adding | operator to select between expressions
re(end)=[]; %// discard the last '|'
```

The resulting regular expression is

```
re =
'\d+ apple|\d+ banana|\d+ orange'
```

Now the actual replacement:

```
newB = regexprep(b,re,'')
```

Resulting with

```
newB = 
' = 2 kiwi'
'1 fig = '
' = 3 strawberry'
```